# Two foreign keys of same class Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How to access the two foreign key's of same class

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)


class bookings(models.Model):
    Pickup = models.ForeignKey(Countries,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Dropoff = models.ForeignKey(Countries,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

ERROR reverse accessor  of Pickup clashes with reverse accessser  for Dropoff
```

Comment: You should define `related_name` for the fields in `booking` model. Like `Pickup = models.ForeignKey(Countries,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name='pickup')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use related name keyword, so that reverse access will be by default it is taking the same name that's why it is conflicting possible.

```
 class bookings(models.Model):
   Pickup = models.ForeignKey(Countries,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name="pickup")
   Dropoff = models.ForeignKey(Countries,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name="dropoff")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your models as below:

```
class bookings(models.Model):
    Pickup = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='pickup_countries')
    Dropoff = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='dropoff_countries')
```

Reference : [Django related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)